# TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know this issue is covered in other posts but I still can't figure out how to make this work - I'm getting the error:

`TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | Function' has no compatible call signatures.`

The console logs a function but I can't call it.

Here is my code:

```js
const func = (): string => 'hi';

const array: (string | Function)[][] = [['string', func]];

const response = array[0][1];

console.log(response); // ƒ () { return 'hi'; }

response(); // TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'string | Function' has no compatible call signatures
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler cannot be sure, that a contained element in `array` is really a function, as you have declared it as union `string | Function`.

To solve that, either declare `array` as a nested tuple `[string, Function][]`

```
const func = (): string => 'hi';
const array: [string, Function][] = [['string', func]];
const response = array[0][1];
response();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKAlALhtAJwEswBzNAPhgHIALI6gbgChRJYBDAgjgTzwDahEqQA0MAGJJgUIuAC6A+WhgCB1YWWrjEyefJZtoMAgFMIAB3ARTKrj14CADIoCMB5mcvXT2RjCA)

or use a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) to check for a function like

```
const func = (): string => 'hi';
const array: (string | Function)[][] = [['string', func]];
const response = array[0][1];

if (typeof response === "function") {
    response()
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKAlALhtAJwEswBzNAPhgHIALI6gbgChRJYBDAgjgTzwyES5AD4wAYkmBQi4LAG0AukrQx586kLLUANPCmLFLNtBgEAphAAO4COdVceveQAZlARiPNmROJii8VuYgfhbWtvaoUTAARIjIMuAxWDAA3swwmWaWNpDm2MwAvkA)